# Web Devtools эмуляция девайса

Tags: html, css, html5, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-devtools

Начинаю изучать основы веб разработки, и заметил небольшую странность с девтулзом хрома.

Имеем следующую HTML страничку:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px;
}

.test1 {
  background: red;
}

.test2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="test1">300px</div>
    <div class="test2">300px</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

На странице выводится два блока по `300px`. Теперь открываю devtools в хроме, запускаю эмуляцию устройства нажатием кнопки [image]. Далее в верхней менюшке добавляю новый девайс

[image]

[image]

И, например, хочу эмулировать устройство `Xiaomi Redmi 5`. Гуглю его характеристики, и указываю в девтулзах

[image]

Device Pixel Ratio не знаю что такое, поэтому укажу `1`

[image]

Добавляю девайс, запускаю все это дело и вижу такую картину:
[image]

Оба блока целиком поместились в область видимости.
Теперь запускаю сайт на реальном устройстве (на физическом). И получается такая картина:

[image]

Зеленый блок на реальном устройстве НЕ помещается в область видимости и обрезается.

Теперь вопрос - почему в девтулзах оба блока целиком поместились в область видимости, а при тестировании на устройстве оказалось, что часть контента урезается? Баг девтулза или я чего то не понимаю?

Благодарю!

Comment: Не смогу ответить развернуто, но разрешение нужно делить на 2, тогда вы получите фактические размеры экрана. Т.е. у вашего редми размеры будут - 360х720

Comment: > Device Pixel Ratio не знаю что такое, поэтому укажу 1 - вот именно в этом и проблема. Физический пиксель на экранах высокой плотности давно не соответствует программному (грубо - один пиксель вашего сайта отображается ЧЕТЫРЬМЯ (2*2) физическими пикселями устройства). Это, с одной стороны, улучшило отбражение шрифтов и векторной графики, с другой - привело к тому, что скриншоты с айфончиков имеют дебильно конские размеры.